# I have unmatched quotes on my \jobname

Tags: formatting, quotation

I have coded

```
\lfoot{\ \\ File \jobname}
```

in order to print the file name at the bottom of each page of my paper.  I prints with quotes thus: ”…” (ie both 99 style quotes).  I expected the quotes to be complementary, thus “…” (ie 66 at the start, and 99 at the end.  Are my expectations unreasonable, or have I made a mistake?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quotes are added to `\jobname` if there is a space in the name, the main use is to act as a valid input string for `\input` so they are necessarily ascii straight quotes `"`  you could typeset it in `\texttt` with a font that sets `"` straight

If you are getting right quotes you are probably using OT1 encoding, as in T1 you get straight quotes with or without using `\texttt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

This is file: \jobname.

This is file: \texttt{\jobname.}


\end{document}
```

The legacy OT1 encoding should be avoided for many reasons but if you use it then using `\texttt` avoids the issue that the right quotes are overloaded with the ascii `"` in OT1.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

This is file: \jobname.

This is file: \texttt{\jobname.}


\end{document}
```

If you rename the file the problem goes away.

[image]